# Previous work Replication and Research ethics Ask Question

Tags: dataset, research, methodology, methods

I am very much concerned about biding by research ethics in my work, especially issues to do with plagiarism. I come across a recent research paper in my field of study that applies state-of-the-art tools (deep learning architectures) in their work using a publically available dataset.

I am impressed by their work and feel I should apply the same methodology they used but using my dataset (private).

Would this be considered a plagiarised version of their work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't think so. If they're publishing their methodology, they want other people to see how well it works and apply it to their work. You'll probably want to explain why you think this method works best for your dataset and compare the performance results to other methods commonly used.

Comment: Many thanks for this piece, I'm totally a naive researcher.